# woocommerce custom product category template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using WooCommerce.

I like the default permalink structure for the Product Category taxonomy that they have included in WooCommerce. It works great. An example:

/product-category/sports-and-outdoors/sports-and-fitness/exercise-and-fitness/ 
/product-category/sports-and-outdoors/sports-and-fitness/ 
/product-category/sports-and-outdoors/ 
... thousands more exist.

However, for every URL above I wish to define a similar URL that has the added "abc" prefix in the url. For example:

/abc/product-category/sports-and-outdoors/sports-and-fitness/exercise-and-fitness/ 
/abc/product-category/sports-and-outdoors/sports-and-fitness/ 
/abc/product-category/sports-and-outdoors/ 
... thousands more

What would I need to define in my child theme so that for every /product-category/* URL (these are generated as I add product categories) that there are also a /abc/product-category/* URL using the same taxonomy slug structure with the exception of the added base "abc". I dont wish to change the permalink base for product category because i want to keep it as-is. I just want to add a /abc prefix to my product category url structure and learn from the community how then to call/display a custom archive template when /abc/product-category/* is requested such that the template echos the same content as would be called when /product-category/* is requested.